Why are charged Particles bent in the opposite direction outside a solenoid magnetic

I Found this picture of the CMS experiment at CERN (their logo is similar) In which we see muons being bent by the solenoid magnet and changing their curvature in the opposite way once outside of it.
Howe er, From my Physics lecture I thought that the magnetic Field was suppose to be equal to 0 outside of the solenoid.
Thanks for and help.

Is the CMS magnet an infinitely long solenoid?

No but how do you explain the Change between inside/out

The design of the magnet is documented in http://cds.cern.ch/record/2773274/files/document.pdf

So there are some flux return yoke. But is there a graph/ equation showing why we have this ?

@Michael Could you give a link to the document with description where this picture was taken?

I actually took this Picture myself at CERN.
